# Unable to complie My java file from my dynamic web project as well as from javac

Tags: classpath, javac

I am generating .java file using java poet API
successfully generated the file but unable to compile

getting error

```
javac BQRUtil.java
QRUtil.java:3: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
QRUtil.java:4: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
QRUtil.java:5: error: package com.google.zxing.common does not exist import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
QRUtil.java:6: error: package com.google.zxing.qrcode does not exist import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
```

Comment: getting error
javac BQRUtil.java
BQRUtil.java:3: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
                       ^
BQRUtil.java:4: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
                       ^
BQRUtil.java:5: error: package com.google.zxing.common does not exist
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
                              ^
BQRUtil.java:6: error: package com.google.zxing.qrcode does not exist
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;

Comment: That's illegible--edit the question.

Comment: You'll probably want to include the classpath when you compile.

Comment: Class path is missing wen u do like javac "{CLASSPATH}" Util.java
IT runs succesfully..same thing i wan to do within code any suggestion Thanks